# How to access the Mailchimp file-manager/files API endpoint using Gibbon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gibbon

I'm using [Gibbon](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/file-manager/files/) to access the [Mailchimp API](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/overview/).

I've no problem using...

```
gibbon = Gibbon::Request.new(api_key: "valid-api-key")
lists = gibbon.lists.retrieve
```

And getting back the lists stored in the account.

However I'm struggling with the [file-manager/files](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/file-manager/files/) API endpoint.

Trying...

```
files = gibbon.file-manager.files.retrieve
```

throws a `undefined local variable or method 'manager' for main:Object (NameError)` error. Which suggests that the `-` sign is not being correctly parsed.

And...

```
files = gibbon.filemanager.files.retrieve
```

returns a 404 error as you'd expect.

So my question : Is this a problem with the Gibbon Gem or is there another way to access the file-manager/files endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I think [you made the right call](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/issues/189) in issuing an issue on their github page :).

I believe their [method_missing magic](https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/master/lib/gibbon/request.rb#L17) is having a little trouble figuring out this hyphen indeed.

Comment: Yeah, until I realised that it does say it in the Readme. I've re-written some of the instructions and submitted a Pull request hopefully that will help someone else out.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that Gibbon expects you to use underscores `_` instead of dashes `-` in the calls.

The correct call is...

```
files = gibbon.file_manager.files.retrieve
```

Comment: Haha, indeed: https://github.com/amro/gibbon/blob/master/lib/gibbon/request.rb#L19